# Authorization in .NET Core for custom JWT

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have currently created a web api using .NET Core Web API and I am succesfully issuing JWT Tokens. A user in my project can belong to one or more "teams" and on each "team" they have a specific role. For example user A belongs to team T1 and has role ABC.

I would like to create an authorization flow to determine if the user is a team member and if the user has enough access to perform that specific request.

I was initially thinking that if User A does not belong to team T1 and makes a POST with the url /api/t1/action I could use the url to determine what team the request is for and then do some sort of comparison with the data in the JWT.

Should this done using middleware, authorization filter or something else? What should I use when applying the next check.

Please advise?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by using the .net core web api's  authorization policies and created a custom one to tailor my applications requirements.